# How to integrate $x^{(r-1)} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\log x)^2} dx$ from x=0 to infinity?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

How to integrate $x^{(r-1)} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\log x)^2} dx$ from x=0 to infinity?

This is the necessary step in Exercise 2.35(a) and Example 2.3.10 from Statistical Inference
Book by George Casella and Roger Lee Berger.

I know the answer is $\sqrt{2 \pi} e^{r^2 /2}$. But how to find this answer?

Comment: Too tired to type an answer right now, but this is really similar to normal distribution so its possible to use the same trick with a double integral i think, or just integrate into an error function and then plug in bounds.

Comment: I try to use u=logx, but I couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130601/integration-by-substitution-in-int-0-inftyxr-frac-1-sqrt2-pixe-log?rq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituting $x=e^u,\frac{dx}{du}=e^u$ gives the equivalent integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ru-u^2/2}\,du$$
Complete the square and linearly change variables to get the canonical Gaussian integral:
$$=e^{r^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(u-r)^2/2}\,du=e^{r^2/2}\sqrt2\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du=e^{r^2/2}\sqrt{2\pi}$$